# Kendogrid returning bad grid on @Html.ActionLink

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, model-view-controller, kendo-grid

I have a Kendogrid with a retry status and retry button as seen below:
[image]

I have a DataBound event that sets each cell in the Status column to a particular color based on that status.  Retry has a button where if you click it I'd like to call a controller action which I've been able to do with this js code:

```
function LineItems_Databound() {
    var grid = $("#Grid").data("kendoGrid");
    var data = grid.dataSource.data();

    $.each(data, function(i, row) {
        var status = row.Status;

        switch (status) {
        case "Retry":
            $($('tr[data-uid="' + row.uid + '"] td')[4])
                .css("background-color", "orange")
            .append('&nbsp @Html.ActionLink("Retry", "TestAction", "Home", null, new { @class = "k-icon k-retry" }) '); 
    }
    });
}
```

From a functionality standpoint, on the click I want to change the status to In-Progress since we're "retrying." But what happens is it brings up a kendogrid with no jquery/css anything as seen in image below:

[image]

This is the code for my TestAction controller action:

```
public ActionResult TestAction()
    {
        TempData["Status"] = "In Progress";
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
```

And finally my question, what am I doing wrong/what do i need to do different to get a result like this:

[image]

Comment: Is this too complicated of a question? Or did I explain it poorly?

Comment: Instead of doing an @Html.ActionLink(). In javascript, bind an event on the refresh arrow. then do an ajax call, and update the dataItem in the success of the ajax call.

Comment: @billybob, I'm willing to go this route but I have no idea where to start.. maybe provide a little code?

Comment: 1- Remove the ActionLink. 2- After the loop bind an event on click on `k-icon k-retry`, call it `onRetry()`. 3- In the click off the button, do an ajax call in `onRetry()` 4- In the c#, do your logic to retry, Send the result in a JsonResult. 5- In the ajax success, update the dataItem.

Comment: Made progress.... How do i access the dataitem? @billybob

Comment: Use UID of the row of the kendo grid. You can get it from the event paramter of the function.